# Is there a way to convert a JavaScript Object/JSON to an equivalent map string?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Having this data sample;

```
{person:'john doe', age:101, town:'Paris'}
```

in javascript I want now to convert it into a string with a specified separator to achieve a result like;

```
person='john doe' + age=101 + town = 'Paris'
```

I Am trying to find a workable solution in vain.

Answer (score 0):

After some workaround, I've managed to come up with this fix.

```js
let obj = { person: "john doe", age: 101, town: "Paris" };
var result = Object.keys(obj)
    .map((v, i) => {
        var vi = typeof Object.values(obj)[i] == "string" ? "'" + Object.values(obj)[i] + "'" : Object.values(obj)[i];
        return v + " = " + vi;
    })
    .join("+ ");
console.log(result);
```